# Deleting database row using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to delete a certain row from database,and i am using while loop to echo them all,and put x sign in the top right corner-so it looks like:

```
echo '<a href="#delete" onclick="delete_post('.$post_id.')">';
```

and then just use

```
function delete_post(post_id)
    {

        $('table').fadeOut(1000, function () {


            // tried adding "var post_id = post_id;";didn't work
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: post_id,
                beforeSend: function()
                {$('.loading_gif').css('display:inline');},
                success: function(response)
                {

                    $("table").html(response);
                    $("table").fadeOut(1000);//sakrivanje tablice kod ajax zahtjeva
                    $('table').fadeIn(1000);//prikazivanje tablice kod ajax zahtjeva

                }
            });
        })}
```

and it fades out and in as it is supposed to but the info stays the same.Ajax request reaches the delete.php beacuse it throws:

Notice: Undefined index: post_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\delete.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\delete.php on line 32

Anyway this is delete.php :

```
 <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Hrvoje
 * Date: 3/17/2015
 * Time: 4:47 PM
 */$mysqli = 'omitted';
//$mysqli ='omitted';// komentirano samo za testiranje,maknuti komentar za live stranicu
if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){echo 'zahtjev';}
$post_id=$_POST['post_id']; // line 10

$delete_query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$post_id'") or die("Failed");


header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');

//$check_db = mysqli_query($mysqli,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(post_id,)");



$txtSmileys = array('&lt;3', ' :P', ' :O', ' :D', ' :(', ' :/', " :'(", ' O:)', ' :X');   // one smylie code for each image
$imgSmileys = array('<img src="srce.jpg"/>', '<img src="p.jpg"/>', '<img src="O.jpg" />', '<img src="D.jpg"/>', '<img src="sad.jpg" />', '<img src="neutral.jpg" />', '<img src="crying.jpg" />', '<img src="anđel.jpg" />', '<img src="x.jpg" />');

// The Regular Expression filter

//example text


$id = intval($_GET['id']); // line 32


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE  posts.poster_id = users.id AND posts.privatnost = 'Javno' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 15;") or die("Database Error");

// run the query. Will return a resource or false

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo '<div class="no_posts">Nemate Objava</div>';
}

// if it ran OK
    $pattern = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

    $_SESSION['id'] = '23368';//need to be amended to receive session value from login.php
    if ($result) {
    echo '<img class="ajax_gif" src="loading_gif.gif" style="margin-top:185px;margin-left:950px;position:absolute;display:none;">';
    echo '<table cellspacing="10" >';// used to display posts in order,continued after while command
    while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $user['post'] = str_replace($txtSmileys, $imgSmileys, $user['post']);// adding smiley
    $user['post'] = wordwrap($user['post'], 60, "\n", TRUE);//spliting string into multiple rows,every 60 characters
    $user['post'] = preg_replace("/@+([a-zA-ZA-z]+)/", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $user['post']);//tagging system,no notification for tagged user
    $user['post'] = preg_replace($pattern, "<a href=\"\\0\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\0</a>", $user['post']);//converting links
    //$user['post'] = preg_replace("/\bfuck\b/i", '****', $user['post']); //censoring system
    $avatar = $user['avatar'];
    $objavljivač = $user['ime'];
    $username = $user['username'];
    $session_poster_id = intval($user['poster_id']);
    $post_id = intval($user['post_id']);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a href="korisnik.php?id='.$session_poster_id.'" style="width:40px;height:40px;">';
    echo '<div class="profile_pic_div" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:5px;width:40px;height:40px;position:absolute;">';
    echo "<img src='$avatar' style='width:40px;height:40px;'>";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<div class="timestamp" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top;font-size:15px;">';
    echo $user['vrijeme'];
    echo '</div>';
    if($_SESSION['id'] == $session_poster_id){
        echo '<a href="#delete" onclick="delete_post('.$post_id.')">';
        echo '<div class="icon-x" style="margin-left:550px;margin-top:-10px;position:absolute;">';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</a>';}
    echo '<div class="post_div" style="margin-top:30px;">';
    if (strlen($user['post']) > 500) {
        $user['post'] = substr($user['post'], 0, 500);
        $user['post'] = substr($user['post'], 0, strrpos($user['post'], ' ')).'... <a href="story.php?post_id='.$post_id.'">Read More</a>';}
    echo  $user['post'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<a href="story.php?id='.$post_id.'">Komentiraj</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';


}

echo '</table>';} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

You're using GET when the AJAX is sending data via POST, but either way there isn't a value called 'id' being sent. Only post_id is set.

```
data: post_id,
```

Comment: if you look closer,you wil see a post_id value defined an line 10

Comment: And as I said, 'id' isn't

Comment: it was originaly intended to use link delete.php?='$post_id',and that's why it uses GET id,the script should complete ajax request without that parameter,i'm more worried beacuse of error:post_id not defined.

Comment: Right... but you're not sending that link in the script you've provided, hence the error on line 32. For the line 10 error, check that post_id is actually set in the JavaScript by using alert(post_id)

Comment: the post_id parameter is set,alert confirms

Comment: Try setting the data type, in a line below data: post_id, put dataType: text,

Comment: now it stopped throwing error,but it still dosent delete the row in database

Comment: Remove '$delete_query=' from the start of line 12. Start it with mysql_query(

Comment: Ok well basically you need to make sure you're connecting to your database properly. Read up on debugging, echo out $post_id on your PHP page to see if it's actually storing the data. There are too many problems it could be to fix over here easily. Try to isolate the problem

Comment: Then your Ajax isn't sending. Change it to dataType: "text" (my mistake)

Comment: now the errors have popped up again...would rewriting the delete.php file help ?

Comment: Delete line 32, you're causing an error as no GET data is being sent

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: post_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\delete.php on line 10

Answer (score 1):

I see line:

```
$mysqli = 'omitted';
```

It shows you do not having any database connection. You need to set it to connect to database using like:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "mydb");
```

Where the paramteres are hostname, username, password and database name.